# SQLAlchemy + MSSQL - Possible to tell using reflection if table column is a computed column?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have a table in MSSQL that uses a number of "computed" columns. Using reflection, is it possible to tell when inspecting one of these columns that they're computed rather than typical columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you use the sys.columns table:

```
   -- object_id - tablename
   -- name - column name
 select case when is_computed=0 then 'Not Computed' 
        else 'Computed'end [Is Computed] 
        from sys.columns 
        where object_id=object_id('dbo.x1') and name ='i1'
```

Comment: This may work for my purpose, things get a bit messy though. Would definitely be preferable if SQLAlchemy's reflection picked this up as part of the column properties. I'll try this out and mark it as answered if I'm able to make this work.